# How can I do an Insert where not exists in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions, not-exists

I am creating a stored procedure to check if username exists and if does not exists insert into user table then gets userid for the same username. This is what I was trying

```
alter Procedure Check_Name
    (--@idn integer,
     @username varchar(25),
     @password varchar(100)
     --@role_id integer)
As
Begin
    INSERT INTO [user] (username, [password]) 
        SELECT 
            username, [password]
        FROM 
            [user] AS u
        WHERE 
            NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [user] AS t
                       WHERE u.username = t.username); 
End
```

When I try to execute it says zero rows affected.. What is the problem?

```
execute Check_Name 'Pope', 'Life2Stressfull';
```

Comment: Your query makes no sense.  You need to insert four columns but only one is listed in the `select`.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you intend something like this:

```
Insert into user(username, password, role_id, date)
    Select @username, NULL, NULL, getdate()
    from user
    Where Not Exists(Select * from user where username = @username);
```

However, I would recommend putting a unique index on `user(username)` and then using a `try`/`catch` block to capture any errors.  I don't think a separate transaction is needed.

Comment: how do u do the error handling?? Begin try...end try BEGIN CATCH
 ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
END CATCH;

Comment: Start with the documentation:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx.